# How to determine if a Twitter user has a default profile image

Tags: image, twitter, profile

I know you can find the profile image of a twitter user using the following url:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger

But how can I determine if it is the default image or the image uploaded by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

> Users who have not uploaded a profile image can be identified by the default_profile_image field of their user object having a true value.